# excel: change format dates in advanced filter

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the Advanced Filter to search between dates in a database.
I placed my criteria side by side so I can seach for one or more information together.

Here is the example:

[image]
This is the code:

```
Sub FiltroAutomatico()
'
' FiltroAutomatico Macro
'

'
    Sheets("BASE_TOTAL_ATUAL").Range("A1:J445").AdvancedFilter Action:= _
        xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range("CONSULTA!Criteria"), 
CopyToRange:=Range _
        ("CONSULTA!Extract"), Unique:=False
    Range("H25").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-15
    Range("G3").Select
End Sub
```

Anyway, the problem is that when I search for something like **>03/03/2017** and **<25/03/2017** it didn't work as I expected.

I think the problem it's because Excel it's not recognizing my dates correctly (my Excel is in portuguese and the date here has the dd/mm/yyyy format). I tested using US dates instead and it worked perfectly.

Is there any way to change the format dates from an Advanced Filter to understand that the format of my criteria is dd/mm/yyyy instead of mm/dd/yyyy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot test this, but dates in VBA filters have always been US-centric.  I would suggest that you have your users enter the actual starting and end date in your local format (but NOT in the actual criteria range).  In the criteria range itself, use this formula:

```
=">" & StartDate
="<" & EndDate
```

Where StartDate and EndDate refer to the dates entered by your user.
You could even leave it in the same physical location as you show above, but have the criteria range elsewhere.  Or you could have them enter it on a User Form.

The cell will display something like `>49076`  where the number is the number of days since (usually) `1/1/1900`.  But it should work.

If you have them enter the dates elsewhere, be sure to `LOCK` and `PROTECT` the criteria cells so the user cannot delete or change the formula.

Comment: Now it works perfectly! I wish I could write directly in my criteria range but it seems that it's not possible... Only if I start to use US dates too.

Comment: @paulinhax You could write directly, but you would have to write something like `=">" & DATE(year, month, day)` so as to provide an unambiguous value.

Comment: I see. Although this isn't the best solution, I guess. Your answer solve the problem better.

Comment: @paulinhax You could also write directly in that range that you show in your screenshot, but use another range for the **real** criteria range, and use VBA to "translate" your `>31/1/2017' string to what is required.

Comment: I tought about changing the criteria, but the whole criteria mixes text and dates so I was in doubt to how to change just part of my criteria to fix the problem... I didn't now if it affects all the range or just one part.